# Spark creates a extra column when reading a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a JSON file into a Spark Dataframe and it creates a extra column at the end.

```
var df : DataFrame = Seq(
  (1.0, "a"),
  (0.0, "b"),
  (0.0, "c"),
  (1.0, "d")
).toDF("col1", "col2")

df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("json").save("/home/neelesh/year=2018/")

val newDF = sqlContext.read.json("/home/neelesh/year=2018/*")
newDF.show
```

The output of `newDF.show` is:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|year|
+----+----+----+
| 1.0|   a|2018|
| 0.0|   b|2018|
| 0.0|   c|2018|
| 1.0|   d|2018|
+----+----+----+
```

However the JSON file is stored as:

```
{"col1":1.0,"col2":"a"}
{"col1":0.0,"col2":"b"}
{"col1":0.0,"col2":"c"}
{"col1":1.0,"col2":"d"}
```

The extra column is not added if year=2018 is removed from the path. What can be the issue here?
I am running Spark 1.6.2 with Scala 2.10.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try:

```
val newDF = sqlContext.read.json("/home/neelesh/year=2018")
newDF.show

+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
| 1.0|   A|
| 0.0|   B|
| 0.0|   C|
| 1.0|   D|
+----+----+
```

quoting from [spark 1.6](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html)

> Starting from Spark 1.6.0, partition discovery only finds partitions
>   under the given paths by default. For the above example, if users pass
>   path/to/table/gender=male to either SQLContext.read.parquet or
>   SQLContext.read.load, gender will not be considered as a partitioning
>   column

Answer (score 1):

Spark uses directory structure field=value as partition information see https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery

so in your case the year=2018 is considered a year partition and thus an additonal column

Comment: Is there any way to turn off partition discovery? For legacy reasons, I need to store and read data from year=2018 folder.

Comment: how about `newDF.drop('year').show()` ? that way your dataframe will not be having `year` as one column